# same cucumber gherkin step but different methods

Tags: overloading, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I have a step

```
Given I have a pass
  |hotel|
```

and

```
Given I have a pass
```

One runs with data and one runs without data. To handle above requirement I wrote two functions:

```
@Given("^I have a pass$")
public void givenIhaveAPass() {

}
```

and

```
@Given("^I have a pass$")
public void givenIhaveAPass(DataTable table) throws Exception {

}
```

but it is giving error `DefinitionTestSuite.initializationError DuplicateStepDefinition Duplicate`

Want to use same step with method overloading. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible since the matching is done with regex only, and not considering the parameters. You can do two just

`Given I have a pass with:
|hotel|`

and

`Given I have a pass`

and match them in your two java methods. This way you can give them a clearer name as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not applicable method in cucumber. There is so much issues opened and closed about your question in [cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues)'s github issues page.

As a work around solution I can suggest following methods. 
When you use `(.*)`, you don't have to provide any arguments just **erase** the 'string' part while you calling step definition :

```
@Given("^I have a pass(.*)$")
public void givenIhaveAPass() {

}

@Given("^I have a pass$")
public void givenIhaveAPass(DataTable table) throws Exception {

}
```